# Turpentine Exclude one domain from varnish for multiple sites on same server

Tags: magento, varnish, multiple-sites

I have multiple sites running on the same server. When i enable the option for normalizing the host name, the other site is also taken to the one on which we have our varnish configured.
Also hostname.com doesn't redirects to www.hostname.com.

If I disable the normalize host name both the sites are running, but their are two frontend cookies set in the same host name due to which when I open the site from the hostname.com on checkout the cart becomes empty.

I have a mobile site which shows a different theme, even when I have enabled the normalize user agent the desktop theme comes up.

Am not able to understand where am going wrong.

Comment: you seem to have an issue of cached stuff being served to wrong people, also there might be a wrong response cached, first of all what's your server structure/configuration and what rules did you add to varnish

Comment: I have not added any special rules to varnish.Am using turpentine magento module to configure varnish with magento. There are a few urls that I have added to the blacklist list and I have enabled normalize user-agent and host in the backend configuration of turpentine. we have also installed memcache and configured it with magento.